# Excel: Comparing text strings in Columns using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been reading on some of the posts that others were having similar issues for comparing text strings in cells.

The results were close but not quite what the goal is so I a confident that I will get the results.
The image attached is just the desired result. Goal: Compare Old SQL (Column B) to New SQL(Column A)/change font color of the difference in Column A (if any).

image attached shows the desired result

[image: image attached shows the desired result]

Being 20 yrs removed, I am beyond rusty.

I have tried the leverstein (?? sorry forget the author); tried dupeword and a couple others. Just havent found the right code. I am going to keep looking at examples - I am sure someone has figured it out - just not me.

```
Public Sub AlignStrings()
Dim a() As Byte, b() As Byte, a_$, b_$, i&, j&, d&, u&, l&, x&, y&, f&()
Const GAP = -1
Const PAD = "$"

a = [a3].Text: b = [b3].Text 'column A &B needs to be a range
'[c2:d2].Clear
'[a1:a6].Font.Name = "Calibri"

ReDim f(0 To UBound(b) \ 2 + 1, 0 To UBound(a) \ 2 + 1)

For i = 1 To UBound(f, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(f, 2)
        x = j - 1: y = i - 1
        If a(x * 2) = b(y * 2) Then
            d = 1 + f(y, x)
            u = 0 + f(y, j)
            l = 0 + f(i, x)
        Else
            d = -1 + f(y, x)
            u = GAP + f(y, j)
            l = GAP + f(i, x)
        End If
        f(i, j) = Max(d, u, l)
    Next
Next

i = UBound(f, 1): j = UBound(f, 2)
On Error Resume Next
Do
    x = j - 1: y = i - 1
    d = f(y, x)
    u = f(y, j)
    l = f(i, x)
    Select Case True
        Case Err
            If y < 0 Then GoTo left Else GoTo up
        Case d >= u And d >= l Or Mid$(a, j, 1) = Mid$(b, i, 1)
diag:
            a_ = Mid$(a, j, 1) & a_
            b_ = Mid$(b, i, 1) & b_
            i = i - 1: j = j - 1
        Case u > l
up:
            a_ = PAD & a_
            b_ = Mid$(b, i, 1) & b_
            i = i - 1
        Case l > u
left:
            a_ = Mid$(a, j, 1) & a_
            b_ = PAD & b_
            j = j - 1
    End Select
Loop Until i < 1 And j < 1

DecorateStrings a_, b_, [a3], [b3], PAD 'output needs to be in same 
columns/range
```

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-routine-to-perform-text-diff.714927/

Comment: Thanks sir, I came across one from a few years ago(@excelhero) that appears to be working on a cell basis. I am coming up empty trying to figure out the syntax error when trying to build for a range of cells with data. Ive tried all the things I remember about ranges and nope - a swing and a miss

Comment: You're more likely to get help here if you post the code you tried, and explain the problem you're having with it.

Comment: Oh I understand. I was trying to figure it out on my own before I did that.